# Pycharm linking css to html file 404

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, flask, pycharm

So I'm trying to link a css file to my html file, but I'm still getting a 404 error. I'm not sure if I have to go into settings or anything to change a path, but does anyone have any insight? I've tried moving things around to different directories, but no luck. I just keep getting this error:

[04/Nov/2017 11:14:04] "GET /templates/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

main.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import render_template, url_for, redirect, request


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 
'postgresql://databasename@localhost/flaskmovie'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(140), unique=True)

def __init__(self, username,email):
    self.username = username
    self.email = email


def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %r>' % self.username


@app.route('/index2')
def index2():
    return render_template('index2.html')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('add_user.html')


@app.route('/post_user', methods=['POST'])
def post_user():
    user = User(request.form['username'], request.form['email'])
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>A Pen by User</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<form>
  <header>Login</header>
  <label>Username <span>*</span></label>
  <input/>
  <div class="help">At least 6 character</div>
  <label>Password <span>*</span></label>
  <input/>
  <div class="help">Use upper and lowercase lettes as well</div>
  <button>Login</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS File:

```
html, body {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: tomato;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

form {
  background: white;
  width: 40%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  font-family: lato;
  position: relative;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
form header {
  background: #FF3838;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
form label {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
form label span {
  color: #FF3838;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2.3em;
  top: -10px;
}
form input {
  display: block;
  width: 78%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
form .help {
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #777;
}
form button {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  font-family: inherit;
  color: white;
  background: #FF3838;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
form button:hover {
  background: #ff5252;
}
```

Directory Hierarchy:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I wasn't using the correct Directory.....